# Problema na inserção da Tabela

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap-4

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Numero par</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label>Número</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend">Nota</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control " id="entrada" placeholder="Numero">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <input type="button" value="Calcular" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="botao()">
    </div>
    <table id="tabela" class="table table-hovers">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Número</th>
                <th scope="col">Pares</th>
                <th scope="col">Soma</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"></th>
                <td id="EntradaPar"></td>
                <td id="EntradaSoma"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
"use strict"
let contador = 1
let par = 2
let soma = 0
function botao() {
    tabela.innerHTML += 
    `
    <td>${entrada.value}</td>
     `
    while (contador <= Number(entrada.value)) {
        soma = soma + par
        EntradaPar.innerHTML += `${par}`
        par = par + 2
        contador++
    }
    EntradaSoma.innerHTML = `${soma}`
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o resultado que estou tendo, gostaria de digitar um número e que ele fique em "Número" os pares dele fique em "Pares" e a soma fique em "Soma"e quando digitar um outro número, pule para linha de baixo e faça a mesma coisa.
O problema é que quando digito um número maior que o anterior ele apenas acrescenta os pares e quando digito um menor, não retorna um resultado.

Comment: Explica o que são as colunas pares e soma com um exemplo válido.

Comment: Por exemplo, se eu digitar o número 4, irá pegar os 4 primeiros números pares. Ex: 2, 4, 6, e 8 e irá retornar a soma desses números "20"... Conseguiu compreender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mudei algumas coisas e o resultado confere com o comentário

```js
"use strict"
  function botao() {
   let contador = 1
   let par = 2
   let pares = '';
   let soma = 0
   while (contador <= Number(entrada.value)) {
    soma = soma + par
    pares += `${par} `
    par = par + 2
    contador++
   }
   tbody.innerHTML += 
   `
   <tr><td>${entrada.value}</td><td>${pares}</td><td>${soma}</td></tr>
   `
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Numero par</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
 <div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label>Número</label>
  <div class="input-group">
   <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend">Nota</span>
   </div>
   <input type="text" class="form-control " id="entrada" placeholder="Numero">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <input type="button" value="Calcular" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="botao()">
 </div>
 <table id="tabela" class="table table-hovers">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th scope="col">Número</th>
    <th scope="col">Pares</th>
    <th scope="col">Soma</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
   
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>

</html>
```